# How to open multiple Globcolour netCDF files and extract the data into a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I ordered netCDF chlorophyll data from 2002 to 2010 of the Caspian Sea region from http://hermes.acri.fr. Then, I got 726 *.nc* files listed in a folder and downloaded them from the FTP site. So now I have 726 time series chlorophyll data in my working directory (time series data and the size is 61 MB).
I am trying to open all of the data (because I want to study changes through time) by `ncdf4`package and extract chlorophyll-a values (pixels):

```
mydata<- nc_open('L3m_20020423-20020430__631633423_4_AV-SWF_CHL1_8D_00')
mydata_extract<- ncvar_get(mydata)
```

But the problem is that I have 726 netCDF file and I have no idea how I can read and extract all extracted chlorophyll-a values into one dataframe or matrix. In fact I need a table rows with  longitude, latitude, time and chlorophyll data from all of these 726 files in one table to apply K-means clustering and classify chlorophyll data based on time and region.
Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Why can't you loop over the file names? How do you want to combine the 726 files? Are they at different times, or do they mosaic over a wider space?

Comment: Actually all of 726 files are time series and also mosaic data from a lake.

Comment: So what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: I want all of the 726 files into a datafram for further analysis. But I do not know how to write a script to read all of it into a matrix

Comment: What columns do you want in your result data frame? What's in `mydata_extract` after your code in your question? Can you point us to a sample data file?

Comment: All of 726 files are .nc files. I want all of these files into a single dataframe

Comment: .nc files are complex structured data files that don't map easily to data frames which are tables with a fixed number of rows and columns. For example I've just got something from "hermes" and it has two matrix structures in it ("CHL-CIA_mean" and "CHL-CIA_flags") and the metadata for the coordinates for those matrixes. You can't just put all that into a data frame, you need to define what you want in each dataframe row.

Comment: Where's the "time" stored? There's a few time-related things in the metadata, like `#period_start_day=20040901` and `#period_end_day` and `#start_time=20040831T220533Z`.

Comment: In fact, all of these 726 files contains 8 day satellite observations from different time and region in a specific area. Data is separated by "time" and "region". Therefore I would like to merge all data to have a matrix from all time and region data.

Comment: How do you get the time given a file?

Comment: Time is specified by the name of each file.

Comment: How? Given a file name, whatever pattern it is, how do you get the time out of it? Which bit of the file name? What is the time format? I can see two possible times in the name in your question. Which one? etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded a random bunch of netCDF files from http://hermes.acri.fr/index.php?class=demonstration_products - I picked a couple of years and drew a region off the coast of the UK. I got 25 files listed and downloaded them from the FTP site.

Let's open one up and see what's in it:

```
> library(ncdf4)
> CHL1 <- nc_open('./L3m_20020901-20020930__802386687_25_AVW-MERMODSWF_CHL-CIA_MO_00.nc')
> names(CHL1$var)
[1] "CHL-CIA_mean"  "CHL-CIA_flags"
```

There are two variables. The first one is:

```
> CHL1$var[[1]]$varsize
[1] 134  48
```

a grid of 134x48 values. I can get that with:

```
> CHLmean = ncvar_get(CHL1, CHL1$var[[1]])
> dim(CHLmean)
[1] 134  48
```

I can get the X and Y coordinates of the grid from the variable metadata:

```
> (longitude = CHL1$var[[1]]$dim[[1]]$vals)
  [1] -30.875 -30.625 -30.375 -30.125 -29.875 -29.625 -29.375 -29.125 -28.875
 [10] -28.625 -28.375 -28.125 -27.875 -27.625 -27.375 -27.125 -26.875 -26.625
 [19] -26.375 -26.125 -25.875 -25.625 -25.375 -25.125 -24.875 -24.625 -24.375
 [28] -24.125 -23.875 -23.625 -23.375 -23.125 -22.875 -22.625 -22.375 -22.125
> (latitude = CHL1$var[[1]]$dim[[2]]$vals)
 [1] 59.625 59.375 59.125 58.875 58.625 58.375 58.125 57.875 57.625 57.375
[11] 57.125 56.875 56.625 56.375 56.125 55.875 55.625 55.375 55.125 54.875
[21] 54.625 54.375 54.125 53.875 53.625 53.375 53.125 52.875 52.625 52.375
```

I can plot this as an image but I have to flip the coordinates:

```
> image(list(x=longitude, y=rev(latitude), z=CHLmean[,length(latitude):1]))
```

[image]

Another easier option is to read the data in directly with the `raster` package:

```
> CHLr = raster("./L3m_20020901-20020930__802386687_25_AVW-MERMODSWF_CHL-CIA_MO_00.nc")
Warning message:
In .varName(nc, varname, warn = warn) : varname used is: CHL-CIA_mean
If that is not correct, you can set it to one of: CHL-CIA_mean, CHL-CIA_flags

> CHLr
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 48, 134, 6432  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -31, 2.5, 47.75, 59.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/Hermes/L3m_20020901-20020930__802386687_25_AVW-MERMODSWF_CHL-CIA_MO_00.nc 
names       : CHL.CIA...Mean.of.the.binned.pixels 
zvar        : CHL-CIA_mean 


> plot(CHLr)
```

[image]

That warns that it has only read the first variable, but if you only have one variable in each NetCDF then that'll do.

So, that's how you read data in from one of them, or at least from one file that might have a good change of being a bit like the files you've got (but you've supplied no data or metadata so its a bit of a guess).

What do you want to do with 726 of them? How can you turn the things into a data frame? Do you want rows with X, Y, Time, and CHL1_mean or whatever variables you've got? This remains unclear. **You should at least now edit your question to show us more of the metadata from the NetCDF you have, including the variable names, sizes, and dimensions.**

Comment: Question has been edited @Spacedman

Comment: Given a raster read in as above, `rasterToPoints(r)` will get you a data frame of x,y, CHL_1mean, and then you can `cbind` the time on it, repeat over all your files.

Comment: How do you open all of the  25 files list of the coast of UK simultaneously?

Comment: You don't  open them all simultaneously, you write a loop, open one at a time, then merge the results. That's basic R programming.